# How to remove invisible chars in bash (tr and sed not working)

Tags: bash

I want to remove invisible chars from a response:

Here is my code:

```
test_id=`clasp run testRunner`
echo "visible"
echo "$test_id"
echo "invisible"
echo "$test_id" | cat -v
echo "invisible2"
echo "$test_id" | tr -dc '[:print:]' | cat -v
echo "invisible3"
echo "$test_id" | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g' | cat -v
echo "invisible4"
printf '%q\n' "$test_id"
```

Here's the output:

```
visible
1d5422fb
invisible
^[[2K^[[1G1d5422fb
invisible2
[2K[1G1d5422fbinvisible3
2K1G1d5422fb
invisible4
$'\E[2K\E[1G1d5422fb'
```

Comment: Doesn't the `clasp` have an option to stop outputting ANSI codes?

Comment: @choroba I didn't find one https://github.com/google/clasp

Comment: What's the problem with `invisible2`? it has all special chars removed.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano `1d5422fb` is the correct output, `invisible2` outputs `[2K[1G1d5422fb`

Comment: but `[`, `2`, `K`, etc. are *printable*

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano why doesn't `echo "$test_id"` print them then? the test ID does not contain `[, 2, K`. I'm not sure why they are there, google clasp is not my code.

Comment: Try using `printf '%q\n' "$invisible"` to see shell-escaped strings.

Comment: @Dave Escape is a nonprinting character. Escape followed by "`[2K`" or "`[1G`" are character *sequences* that will be interpreted by an ANSI-compliant terminal as nonprinting. You need to remove the entire escape *sequences*, not just the individual nonprinting characters.

Comment: @GordonDavisson that makes sense, I don't know how to do it in bash though

Comment: @Dave Whether something is "invisible" is entirely dependent on which terminal you intend to display it. Removing them amounts to writing a good chunk of a terminal emulator, because `echo` prints *everything*; the terminal decides what to actually display on-screen.

Comment: There's a perl script in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012530/generate-documentation-from-shell-output/51180919#51180919) that will remove ANSI standard escape sequences.

Comment: @chepner Almost all terminals use ANSI control sequences, so it's pretty standard what's visible vs invisible.

Comment: There are some similar string-cleanup scripts in the answers to [this unix&linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output).

Answer (score 1):

The following code works with your example:

```
shopt -s extglob
test_id=$'\e[2K\e[1G1d5422fb'
test_id="${test_id//$'\e['*([^a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]}"
echo "$test_id" | cat -v
```

The crucial part is the third line, which applies a string substitution to the expanded variable. It matches (and removes) all occurrences of the pattern

- `$'\e['` - a single <kbd>Esc</kbd> character followed by `[`
- `*( ... )` - (this is what `extglob` is needed for) zero or more occurrences of ...

  - `[^a-zA-Z]` - a single non-alphabetic character
- `[a-zA-Z]` - a single alphabetic character

In your example this gets rid of the two escape sequences `\e[2K` (erase line) and `\e[1G` (move cursor to column 1).

Comment: adding `shopt -s extglob
test_id="${test_id//$'\e['*([^a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]}"` didn't seem to have any effect to any of the outputs

Comment: @Dave What exactly did you add where, and what outputs?

Comment: @Dave Did you save your changes? Are you running the same script you're editing?

Comment: pretty sure, but I found a solution from the comments anyway already

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the escape sequences prevent them from being generated, which I guess you can do with

```
test_id=$(TERM=dumb clasp run testRunner)
```

Comment: Well, clasp doesn't care about the TERM variable (`grep -rl TERM clasp` outputs `clasp/LICENSE`) but some external calls might support it.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
echo "solution"
echo "$test_id" | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | cat -v
```

as per @Dave's edit on his own question.